# AV Foundation: Cannot Find Error Code Reference

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation

I'm working on an iOS camera application that takes photos on a timer. It seems to work well for about a minute and then it will intermittently fail to capture photos. I pick up this error in the `didFinishProcessingPhoto` portion of AVFoundation's Photo Capture Delegate:

`Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11830 "Cannot Take Photo" UserInfo={AVErrorRecordingFailureDomainKey=3, NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Take Photo, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try taking a photo again.}`

Does anyone know where I can find a reference to this error? I can't find Code=-11830 anywhere and there has to be something more descriptive than just "Cannot Take Photo".

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far. Like how you take the photo, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-11830` is `AVErrorMaximumStillImageCaptureRequestsExceeded`, which is [actually documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/averror/averrormaximumstillimagecapturerequestsexceeded?changes=_7&language=objc) (!!!)

> Your app can’t take a photo because there are too many unfinished photo capture requests.

Are you deliberately taking many photos at once? If so check out `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`. These allow higher framerate video capture. Note that the formats are different to photo style presets.

Comment: Thanks! I could not find that documentation earlier!

I **am** deliberately taking that many photos at once. It's for a research project and is designed to capture separate photos from each of the 3 hardware cameras (on iphone 12 pro). I don't need a frame rate as high as video -- but was trying to get 1 photo from each camera about every ~ 0.5 seconds.

Is there a way to keep from running into this error with that many photos? Like multi-threading the photo processing? If not, any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this kind of error occur due to phone storage related issues, please check if your phone has enough memory also try again with app relaunch or phone restart.